# Solve $x^2 = 2^n + 3^n + 6^n$ over positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Solve $x^2 = 2^n + 3^n + 6^n$ over positive integers.

I have found the solution $(x, n) = (7, 2)$. I have tried all $n$'s till $6$ and no other seem to be there.

Taking $\pmod{10}$, I have been able to prove that if $4|n$ that this proposition does not hold. Can you give me some hints on how to proceed with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: A somewhat obvious one $$2^n+3^n+6^n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$$ if $n$ is a odd value larger than $3$. Thus it is impossible for odd numbers as well.

Comment: @Dhruv, no perfect squares up to $n=200$. Or up to $n=300$ either.

Comment: Well, I don't think my comment provides an answer. The case $n \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ is difficult, is it not?

Comment: @MXYMXY Yes, it doesn't provide an answer but it does provide a lead.

Comment: Yep, and I think that you can't solve this with quadratic residues either.

Comment: The given equation is equivalent to $$(2^n+1)(3^n+1)=x^2+1$$. Modulo $3$, we also see that $n$ must be even because of $2^n\equiv (-1)^n$.

Comment: For  $n\in [0,10^5]$, there is no other solution than $n=2$.

Comment: @Peter Make that $10^6$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n=2k+1\ge 3$, then $x^2\equiv 3\mod 4$.
If $n=2k\ge 4$, then $(x+2^k)(x-2^k)=x^2-2^{2k}=6^{2k}+3^{2k}=3^{2k}(1+2^{2k})$.
We have $\gcd (x-2^k, x+2^k)=1$, then 
$x+2^k\ge 3^{2k} \Rightarrow x-2^k\ge 3^{2k}-2^{2k+1}>2^{2k}+1$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So the proof relies on the fact that $3^{2k}$ and $2^{2k}+1$ are relatively prime?

Comment: No! i don't use this fact. I use that $(x-2^k)$ and $(x+2^k)$ approximatly equal, but only one can be divided by 3.

Comment: Doesn't it mean the same? They are relatively prime implies that $3$ does not divide $1+2^{2k}$. So, it means that exactly one of $x\pm 2^k$ is divisible by 3. Since, one value of the RHS is equal to one of the LHS

Comment: @Dhruv If $3\mid x-2^k$, then $3^{2k}\mid x-2^k$ because $x-2^k, x+2^k$ are coprime, so $x-2^k\ge 3^{2k}>1+2^{2k}\ge x+2^k$, contradiction. Therefore $3\mid x+2^k$, so $3^{2k}\mid x+2^k$, so $x+2^k\ge 3^{2k}$, so $x-2^k\ge 3^{2k}-2^{k+1}>1+2^{2k}$, so $\left(x+2^k\right)\left(x-2^k\right)>3^{2k}\left(1+2^{2k}\right)$, contradiction.

Comment: @user236182 Thanks. I got it.